# c# webservice client - date format

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime, webservice-client

I'm writing a c# app that consumes a web service with datetime type parameter in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format. Notice that the parameter is "DateTime" type in web service hence I dont have control over how this type will get formatted when its converted to XML internally.

Can anyone provide a clue on how we can ensure that our web service calls send datetime in required format?

Comment: What format do you want it sent it?

Comment: Format should be yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss. Since this is a HTTPS based web service, I am not able to see request XML in fiddler. Having said that, i created my own web service that takes a datetime type as parameter, i notice that, in XML, request datetime format is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+05:30. Notice that timezone is getting added to the datetime format. Is there a way to supress how my datetime should go in request?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you send the parameter as an object of the type `DateTime` you dont have to worry, the `DateTime` Object stores the data internally not as a string. You just have to make sure that at the moment when you create your client side DateTime object you parse it correctly.

EDIT:
of course the parsing of the date in a test-interface (where you enter a string) will not be the same as when you pass directly a datetime object to the client proxy...

what you asked in your comment: to supress the timezone which gets added you can set the attribute `dateTimeSerialization` to `local`.
But I dont think thats a good idea. just better use localized dates everywhere.
[more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229751%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I did send it without worrying about formatting but getting error from web service "Input date is not in correct format". WebService folks have provided a test interface where I can manually type in parameters. On this test interface, if i enter date like 2012-07-20T12:45:00, it returns desired results.